# I can't solve this equation, is it my or book's error?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I found this in my book but whatever I do I can't solve it

$$(2x + 3)^2 - (1 + 2x)(2x - 1) = x^2 - (x - 1)^2 $$

it says that the solution is $\{-1.1\}$. Am I doing something wrong or not?

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: Put in the values...is it satisfied?

Comment: both values don't solve the equation...

Comment: If you just expand everything and collect terms it will just be normal quadratic.

Comment: It's actually a linear equation, hence can't have exactly 2 solutions.

Comment: Maybe the OP is from a country where `,` is used as the decimal point?  That might be the source of confusion.

Comment: I put in the value -1.1 and yet I can't get a true equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the answer is {-1.1} and not {-1,1} :)

This can be easily verified by substitution.

To solve, expand both sides:  $x^2$ terms cancel out, leaving $10x=-11$.

Comment: Ok I tried it like this: 

$$ 4x^2 + 12x + 9 - (2x - 1 + 4x^2 - 2x) = x^2 - (x^2 + 2*x*(-1) + (-1)^2 $$  # 2x and -2x removed#

$$ 4x^2 + 12x + 10 - 4x^2 = x^2 - (x^2 + 2x + 1) $$  again removing 4x^2 and -4x^2

$$ 12x + 10 = -2x - 1 $$

$$ 12x + 2x = -10 - 1 $$

$$14x = -11 $$

And as you can see I don't get 10x=−11, where did I make a mistake?There is nothing to expand here.

Comment: Check your RHS expansion...

Comment: What is RHS expansion?

Comment: @user3711671 It means 'right-hand side'.

Comment: @user3711671, in second line from top you should have $x^2-(x^2-2x+1)$ after "=" sign on right hand side and so in third line from bottom's right hand side should be"$=2x-1$"

Comment: How did you get that?It's
$$ (x - 1)^2 $$
so $$ (x^2 - 2 * x * (-1) + (-1)^2)$$ minus 2 after first $$ x^2 $$ and -1 give a positive number 2 so it's 2x, then after squaring -1 we get +1 and at the end we have

$$ (x^2 + 2x + 1) $$ :\ how did you get a minus there?

Comment: @user3711671: Check again.  If you use the distributive law to multiply $(x-1)(x-1)$, you get $x^2 + 2*x*(-1) + (-1)^2$ which is $x^2-2x+1$, not $x^2+2x+1$.

Comment: But what happened to the rule of squared binomial that says $$ a^2 + (or minus) 2ab + b^2 $$?When you do this (a + b) * (a+b) you will get the result above but when you do (x-1)*(x-1) you will get a + instead of minus unlike solving it by the rule of squared binomial, why?This is the first time that the formula above doesn't work.